# Is there any background tasks limit when fcm recived same as Android on IOS?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

FCM android document says:

> To receive messages, use a service that extends FirebaseMessagingService. Your service should override the onMessageReceived and onDeletedMessages callbacks. It should handle any message within 20 seconds of receipt (10 seconds on Android Marshmallow).

I am using `FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(_firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler);` on flutter, And is there any smilier limit on IOS as well? I am tring to fetch some data in `_firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler` but a bit worry about background tasks could time out on ios.